# Minimum installation for showing CURRENT / TOTAL INSTALLS on Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have published two apps on **Google Play Store** and curious to know if there are some constraints to show **CURRENT / TOTAL INSTALLS** because it's more than 24 hours and it still blank while *ratings are showing for both the apps*.

Is there some 50 100 or so installation then only Google will show up the data?

Comment: For me it took 3 days to show.. So wait and see

Comment: and what about minimum installation?

Comment: First number it showed me was 50-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no minimum value of installs to show them.

So you can see only 1 installation of your app in your list.
If you press on your app and choose statistics tab you will see that stats are collecting about a 2 days before current day.

So you should wait 2-3 days to see previous days statistics.